# Socket IO Server Clusters working with Redis Pub/Sub

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

So firstly, I have built a microservice that fetches Football API, and thru pub/sub system of redis, it publishes any changes if there are any for livescores.

Now my server, with sockets and routes, will be in cluster mode. I already set this up with socketio-redis. Here is a snippet of this set up:

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
const sRedis = require('socket.io-redis');
const adapter = sRedis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });
const { promisify } = require('util');
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('livescore');



io.adapter(adapter);
const ioa = io.of('/').adapter;
ioa.clients = promisify(ioa.clients);
ioa.clientRooms = promisify(ioa.clientRooms);
ioa.remoteJoin = promisify(ioa.remoteJoin);
ioa.remoteLeave = promisify(ioa.remoteLeave);
ioa.allRooms = promisify(ioa.allRooms);

// notice this listener
redis.on('message', (channel, message) => {
    io.emit('livescore', message);
})


io.on('connect', async (socket) => {

    socket.clientRooms = () => ioa.clientRooms(socket.id);
    socket.remoteJoin = (room) => ioa.remoteJoin(socket.id, room);
    socket.remoteLeave = (room) => ioa.remoteLeave(socket.id, room);
    socket.remoteDisconnect = () => ioa.remoteDisconnect(socket.id);


    socket.on('join room', async (id) => {
        await socket.remoteJoin(id);
        socket.emit('join room', `You have joined room ${id}`)
        socket.broadcast.emit('join room', `${socket.id} has joined.`)
    });

    socket.on('leave room', (id) => {
        socket.remoteLeave(id);
    });


})

module.exports = io;
```

So, if I run single instance of this node app, everything works perfectly.

But if I run it in cluster mode, let's say there are 4 clusters (I'm running cluster mode with pm2), the following happens:

1. Microservice publishes event.
2. Each cluster has a subscription on 'livescore' channel
3. Each cluster does io.emit() (to all clients)
4. Client get 4 same events at almost same time.

I figured out why the client gets 4 same events, but I wanna know what is the right way of handling this?

My only thought on solution is that I only do redis sub on one cluster, and publish everything from that one, but I fear that would be too much job for one cluster?

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find its solution?

Comment: any update on finding solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple solutions to fix it, you could for example:

### Use a message queue instead of pub/sub

Depending on the number of processing, you probably only want one node it process the message. A pub/sub is not what you want in that case. You could for example store your messages in a list and use the [LPOP](https://redis.io/commands/lpop) command to get and delete a message. Then you could say the "first one catches it" - this way only one of your servers will do the work, but a random one basically.
You could also use a distinct message queue like RabbitMQ, SQS, etc.

### Use socket.io-emitter to send messages

Since you're using socket.io-redis anyway, your messages get distributed to your nodes. There's a project which is part of socket.io-redis, it's called [socket.io-emitter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-emitter). That can be used to send messages to all your nodes without being one itself. When you implement that in your worker microservice (the one that writes the message to "livescore" at the moment), you can send messages directly to your clients.
That might not work if you need to process the messages in your node app though.